# django rest Serializers how to representation

Tags: python, django, rest

in django models

```
class TableFriend(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="main_user", default="newbie")
     friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friend_for_user", default="newbie")
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return '%s %s %s'  % (self.user, self.friend, self.date)
```

django rest code

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TableFriend
        fields = ('user', 'friend', 'date')
```

output:

```
[{"user":1,"friend":3,"date":"2016-11-10T15:12:33.189570Z"},{"user":1,"friend":2,"date":"2016-11-10T15:11:56.936230Z"}]
```

But I need the name of friends.
I want see `"friend":username`.
I want to see also `__str__` from django model.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your `__str__` in `TableFriend`, you would need to actually pass a string like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.user.name, self.friend.name, self.date)
```

I'm assuming you have a `name` field in the `User` model.

To display the friend username, you would do:

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    friend_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='friend.username')

    class Meta:
        model = TableFriend
        fields = ('user', 'friend', 'date')
```

Ref: [Specifying read only fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly)

The output will now be something like:

```
[{"user":1,"friend":3,"friend_username":"<the_username>","date":"2016-11-10T15:12:33.189570Z"}...]
```

The `__str__` is a string representation of the object.
To see it, you would do something like: `TableFriend.objects.first()`.
This would give an output like `<TableFriend: my_name friend_name 2016-11-21 23:54:57.060029>`

Ref: [object.**str**(self)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Comment: thanks, fields true for work>>  fields = ('user','friend','friend_username', 'date')